# Save user profile picture to firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, firebase-storage

Good Afternoon, I am trying to allow users to save their profile picture in firebase. my application runs without a crash. however, when I select a picture it doesn't save to the system. I have a ViewController, and an extension file that I have been placing my code in. I will place below. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. Hopefully, this question will help others who are facing the same issues.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class EditProfileVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupProfileImageView()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}
func setupProfileImageView() {
    view.addSubview(profileImageView)
    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive=true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 60
    profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
   var randomString = UUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child;"\(randomString).png")

    if let uploadImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!) {

        storageRef.putData(uploadImage, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error upload data to Firebase Storage. Detail: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            if let profileImageURl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
            self.registerUser(UserId: userId, profileImageURL: profileImageURL) {
            }
        }
    }
    }

}
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "users")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}()

}
```

// This is my extension file

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
extension EditProfileVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

@objc func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.allowsEditing = true

present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage as? UIImage
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage as? UIImage
    }        
    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        profileImageView.image = selectedImage
    }

    print(info)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("Canceled Picker")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
 }
```

My app doesn't crash when I run it. It's just no images are stored in firebase. I want users to click onto the EditProfileVC, then be able to change their profile picture and have it save. If anyone can help me solve this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.